# Google snippet customisation

Tags: seo, google, google-search

Some months ago i created a website for a friend of mine.
Now i want to do a little SEO on this website.

Thing is, that when you search for this website on google, it looks like this:
[image: bad google result]

It is because of the index page, that shows up the logo, and where you can choose your language.

In fact, there is no plain text on this website, all datas are displayed with javascript.

I want to make google shows result like this for example:

[image: good google result]

I know that it's bad to manipulate google search engine, as explained in the Google’s Webmaster Guidelines.

So i need help or tips, as i'm not an SEO expert at all.

The website is in fact one index.php that contains all datas, and datas are displayed with innerHTML() javascript function when needed.

Thanks in advance for your answers, feel free to ask me some additional infos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is rather easy. You do not have a description meta-tag. Search engine result page (SERP) snippets generally come from the description meta-tag though another closer matching content snippet can be used instead to satisfy the searchers intent.

While the site does look good, you have made some fundamental SEO mistakes.

Your `title` tag is too simplistic. It does not include the top 2-3 most important keywords for your site. `Title` tags should not be over 50 characters. The actual limit is 512 pixels where wider characters such as Q, W, M, G, and so on will limit the actual number of characters. The range you want to hit is 45-50 characters keeping it to less than 512 pixels.

You are missing a `description` meta-tag. This should contain the top 2-3 most important keywords plus a few more that searchers will likely use to find your site. This is crucial. While it is argued that `description` meta-tag keywords do not carry much weight, it is absolutely true that keyword matches are made against the `description` meta-tag likely more times than most tags.

You are also missing an `h1` tag. This is important. The `h1` tag supports the `title` tag and should contain the top 2-3 most important keywords for your site and should not be a duplicate of the `title` tag though it can be somewhat similar.

You are not using other header tags (`h2`, `h3`, `h4`, ...) These are important to contain the other more important keywords for your site.

**Without these elements, this site can never rank.**

Other issues:

Your style and JavaScript is in-line. This should not be. Technically it is okay, but adds weight to the page and is better of separated out into .css and .js files. In fact, your JavaScript was messing up my computer by making it kinda "loogie" so I had to hit the back button so that I could finish typing this answer.

As well, the single page design is terrible for SEO unless it can appear as several real pages to the search engine. In this case, you will want to use parameters that make each relative page of content look like a separate page. The reason is simple. Search engines still favor old-school pages of content.

*This does not mean that a one page site cannot rank. It can.*

However, search engines will not effectively index your site. I did a site: search against your domain name and only one SERP listing comes up.

Lastly, search engines like sites that have content. This is no secret these days. You are far better off creating helpful content to attract users and using carefully selected keywords for each page to cover the topic spectrum. We can discuss this at another time when you get to that point.